# html/css problem with object-fit property in IE

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage and it works well in chrome browser.
But in IE7, its structure has changed and it looks not that good.
Especially,  contents has stretched vertically. I've checked the css and found that object-fit property doesn't work on IE.
What is the reason? Why does the structure change? I'd like you to help me.
Thanks for your consideration.
[This is chrome's capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaHkH.png)
[this is IE's capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9pYk.png)

Comment: Please share your code. Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Internet Explorer does not support the property at all, you can see it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: see https://caniuse.com/?search=object-fit too

Comment: You need it to work in a 14-year-old browser? 

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Jarlik Stepsto. But there is no way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

object-fit is not implemented in any version of IE

see https://caniuse.com/?search=object-fit

Some versions of IE (but not as far back as IE7) support background-image-size:contain which is similar to obect-fit for background-images which you may be able to use instead of imgs in some circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in my case, I've used <a> tag and it includes img tag. How do i have to do in this case?

Comment: Instead of the img you could use a div (of suitable size) and give it a background-image:url(your imagenurl) and background-size: contain (and if necessary background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat). But it'll have to be on a more uptodate IE

Answer (score 0):

Your Webpage will look diffrently on Chrome/IE/Edge/Firefox, because some features are only available for Chrome f.e. when you wanna know what feature/property do work on which browser, you might wanna take a look on: [enter link description here](https://caniuse.com/) just search for your property and it will show you where it will work. When you need to only change propertys for one browser, take a look on this article [enter link description here](https://www.ryadel.com/en/css3-media-query-target-only-ie-ie6-ie11-firefox-chrome-safari-edge/)

And for some propertys you need to use vendor-prefixes. More on that topic [here](https://www.lifewire.com/css-vendor-prefixes-3466867). But basically you create a second property for the diffrent browsers, for example in IE you use the prefix "`-ms-`", so when your normal property doesnt work, it will try this one.